# FMDB not inserting into DB

Tags: iphone, fmdb

I am trying to use FMDB to insert a few queries into the DB. 
When I check the query for insert it is saying that it is inserting. 
Later I can actually read the data from the Tables. 
But what happens is that if I try to read the information from the DB, it comes back as null. 
 When I checked the DB in the Xcode Project, not seems to have updated. 
It kind of confusing me. Any suggestion what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you use `db.traceExecution = YES` and `db.logsErrors` to check what's going on?

Comment: Just checked both db.traceExecution and db.logsErrors. Shows no errors and shows the transactions.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to read from the DB?

Comment: NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSError *error;
 NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydatabase.db"];
 
 database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:defaultDBPath];
  
 FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM myList"];
 
 if([database open])
 {
  while ([rs next]) {
 
  NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@",
     [rs stringForColumn:@"my_id"],
     [rs stringForColumn:@"my_name"],
     [rs stringForColumn:@"my_loc"]);
     
  
  }
  
  [rs close];
  [database close];
 }

Comment: I have notice something, where the DB is located in the iPhone Simulator. It is has no table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong. This is what I use to write:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];

FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
[db open];

[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (?)", bar];

[db close];
```

And to read:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [db open];

    NSMutableArray *bar = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"select * from foo"];
    while ([s next]) {

        [bar addObject:[s stringForColumn:@"bar"]];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@", bar);

    [db close];
```

Also checkout where I located the db. I think doing your way will work on simulator but not on the device because of sandboxing and all.

Good luck!

EDIT:

Put this in your app delegate:

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {


    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

And run that method from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded) withObject:nil];
```

Be sure that you put your database in your projecttree first.

Comment: Yeap. Its not inserting into the DB. Could it be the path of my DB? I have it in root folder.